# Serve static .json file in Nodejs with expressjs and serve-static

Tags: json, node.js, static-files

I Have the following code:

```
...
var servceStatic = require("serve-static");
var app = express();

app.use(express.compress());
app.use(servceStatic('static'));
...
```

Somehow it manages to serve all kind of files except those that end with ".json". Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

you don´t need this module serve-static, because it is build in in express:

create a public folder and than just add this line to your code after your instantiation of express:

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This should hand out all your files including the JSON files.

Comment: Just tried this and json files still returns a blank page :(

Comment: @danielrvt What was your solution?

Answer (score -1):

> [serve-static#index](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#index): By default this module will send “index.html”
>   files in response to a request on a directory. To disable this set
>   false or to supply a new index pass a string or an array in preferred
>   order.

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', {
    'index': ['index.json', 'index.html', 'index.htm'],
}));
```